# Gas stovetop repair: What anti seize to use on brass fittings?

Tags: appliances, range, gas-burner

I am repairing a gas range.

The brass venturi tubes are threaded, and seem to seize up, even when metallic anti seize paste is used. (And when that happens, I have to drill out the venturi, which means $60-130 in replacement parts!)

These parts get very hot. (They are part of the burner assembly.) Typically, they have to be drilled out because the threads on the brass venturi weld themselves over time to the base jet assembly. Again, this is due to heat.

I am considering trying ceramic anti seize paste this time.

What type of anti seize is the best way to go for this application?

Comment: If heat is the issue, then something used in automotive engines seems like it might be something to consider

Comment: @Ack Thanks! What I have used in the past is a metallic anti seize, that is primarily used in automotive applications. But my application here is on brass parts, where on engines it is steel and iron...

Comment: Perhaps look into boating, they use a lot of brass due to the wet conditions and corrosion issues. They generally don't use brass in high heat but it might be worth a shot

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tightening brass fittings to the point where they seize, you are tightening them way too tight!

Propane and natural gas at the stove or oven normally only have approximately 0.75 psi in residential, and 2 psi in commercial in my area. By the time it's being throttled at a Venturi/air mixing point, it's less than that.

The only thing that should used on gas pipe threads is listed PFTE tape, normally yellow or yellow listed pipe dope. If you are seizing fittings you have the wrong threads matched or are way over-tightening the fittings.

Comment: Ed, Thanks, but I think you got on the wrong foot. I enhanced the OP. If you get a chance, please review.

Comment: Adding the heat makes a big difference normally the venturi’s are on the input side of the air Mix and do not get that hot. I think Coper coat anti seize is one of the best, we use that on head bolts and exhaust bolts all the time.